# How to determine if native apk / JS bundle has to be created for apps with RN >=0.60

Tags: android, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I have been using code-push in production for more than 2 years.

**How I implemented?**

- Whenever android folder of my react native app was modified, I assumed there is a native change and my CI/CD tool created a native apk file.
- In all other cases, I generated an JS bundle and pushed via CodePush.

In the latest RN version >=0.60, we have auto-linking of native modules. Because of this, I am not able to identify if any library newly added requires a native APK to be generated or just a bundle update.

Please provide suggestion how can this be done?

**Environment**

react-native-code-push version: 6.0.0

react-native version: 0.61.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all those people who have similar needs. Here's what I did.

- My app supports both android and ios, therefore whenever we add a native module it is mandatory for us to do `cd ios && pod install` this step will update the `Podfile.lock` file.
- When the code is pushed to repo and CI/CD Pipeline is triggered, I check my git history to see if `android/` or `ios/` folder was updated with files.
- If yes, I trigger my native build else I do codepush.

Here's help on how to do conditional pipelines on Circle CI. https://medium.com/labs42/monorepo-with-circleci-conditional-workflows-69e65d3f1bd0

```
FILES_CHANGED=`git diff --name-only $1 $2 | grep "android/\|ios/"`

PARAMETERS='"trigger": false,'
if [[ $FILES_CHANGED == '' ]]; then
  PARAMETERS+='"js": true'
  echo "JS Code changes detected..."
else 
  PARAMETERS+='"native": true'
  echo "Native Code changes detected..."
fi
```

Above snippet of shell code helps check the files changed.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on the "I check my git history to see if android/ or ios/ folder was updated with files." ? :)

Comment: Great, helps alot! :)